# Memoization using dictionary

Tags: python, memoization

So I am trying to implement Lowest common subsequence in Python and was trying this alternative to my previous solution. I tried using a dictionary instead of a 2-D matrix to memoize the results.

```
def lcs(s1, s2):

    cache = {}
    if len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
        return 0
    if (s1, s2) in cache:
        return cache[s1, s2]
    else:
        if s1[-1] == s2[-1]:
            cache[s1, s2] = 1 + lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1])
        else:
            cache[s1, s2] = max(lcs(s1[:-1], s2), lcs(s1, s2[:-1]))
    print cache
```

It's returning

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

which I understand is because I am not returning anything so how can I do something like this.

```
return cache[s1, s2] = 1 + lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1])
```

And I am trying to implement it without using any decorators.

Comment: `cache` can't be local to the function that you are trying to memoize

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
cache = {}
def lcs(s1, s2):
  global cache
  if len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
      return 0
  if (s1, s2) in cache:
      return cache[(s1, s2)]
  else:
      if s1[-1] == s2[-1]:
          cache[(s1, s2)] = 1 + lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1])
      else:
          cache[(s1, s2)] = max(lcs(s1[:-1], s2), lcs(s1, s2[:-1]))
  return cache[(s1, s2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was trying to implement something like this and your solution worked. It's more intuitive that creating a 2-D matrix for storing results.

Comment: Good. Mark the answer as correct answer so that other can get benefit of this.

Comment: I always like dictionaries for memoization.